# How to Test Game in Android Device?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new In Unity So I don't know How to run my Game which I created Recently and I Have seen many tutorials on It But When I connect My device with my Pc and I try to open my project Setting but It doesn't Detect any Device.

Can any body Tell me What I am Missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you set your android sdk path in unity

Edit -> Preferneces -> External tool -> set your path in Android SDK Location.

Now go to

File -> Build Settings -> Platform (select android). and Change Player Settings .

after that click on 'Build and Run' now your project run with your connecting devices.
If you have onliy apk File then click only 'Build'